# PHP explode to detect username

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, explode, detect

I'm trying to build a PHP code to detect a twitter-like mention, but rather than linking to the @username, I'm locating the user's ID and referring to that.

```
function get_user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitise($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_sitename = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

$string = sanitise($_POST['updatetext']);
$explosion = explode("@", $string);
$count = count($explosion);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $explosion2 = explode(" ", $explosion[$i]);
    $explosion2 = $explosion2[0];

    $username_id = get_user_id_from_username($explosion2);

    $string = str_replace("@{$explosion2}", "<a href='profile.php?id={$username_id}'>{$explosion2}</a>", $string);
}
```

The issue I'm having is the username will only be detected if the @username isn't followed by punctuation, however if the $update is equal to "Hello @username, are you OK?" the query won't find a username equal to "username," and so throws an error.

Is there a way I can end the explode once any piece of punctuation exists? So rather than $explosion2 being equal to "username," it's equal to "username"?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `explode`, just do:

```
preg_match_all('/@[A-Za-z]+/',$string,$usernames);
```

That will give you an array of usernames, `$usernames` which you can then loop over to do your DB lookup. Note that the usernames will include the `@` - you'll need to strip that out before doing the lookup.

I've assumed that usernames consist entirely of letters - if you want to allow for numbers or other characters just adjust the regexp accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's trim() function to remove all punctuation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

i.e.:

```
$explosion2 = trim($explosion2, ",.");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this:

```
preg_split('/[.,;?!]/',$mystring);
```

where mystring would be what the user typed in an u can add all punctuation marks between [] in the code.. or you can just replace the string:

```
u can also remove the punctuations with preg_replace
preg_replace("/[^@[a-zA-Z 0-9]]+/", " ", $mystring);
```

then get the link and place the punctuation from the original string.. and a lot of tweaks you can think of..